# Question about Certain Upper Bounds of the Sum of Divisors Function

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum

It has been proven that $$\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n \ln \ln n}=e^\gamma$$ where $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of divisors and $\gamma$ is Euler's constant ($0.5772...$). The way I understand it is that for every $\epsilon$, there is some $b$, so that when $n>b$, $(e^\gamma + \epsilon)n \ln\ln n>\sigma(n)$. Is there a way to find such smallest $b$ for every $\epsilon$ to make above inequality true (that is, for any smaller $b$, the inequality wouldn't hold)? If there is not a way to find the exact smallest $b$, is there at least a way to find a "tight" estimate/upper bound (any smaller estimate/upper bound wouldn't work) on such smallest $b$?

Comment: What do you mean with "smallest". The definition of $\lim \sup$ is $f(n) = \sup_{m \ge n} \frac{\sigma(m)}{m \ln \ln m}$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}f(n) = e^{-\gamma}$. The latter follows from Mertens theorems. The best known estimates for $f(n)$ are in the papers about Robin Lagarias criterion for the RH.

Comment: @reuns  When I say "smallest", I mean for any smaller $b$, the inequality wouldn't hold.

Comment: I have defined $f(n)$. You need to use quantifiers : to clarify why to deal with limits we say "$\forall \epsilon >0,\exists b,....$"

Comment: @reuns Whoops, I didn't see that definition. Sorry. Also, what do you mean by "quantifiers"?

Comment: so did you mean "for all $\epsilon> 0$" or "for all b" or ...

Comment: @reuns Sorry, I meant that for every $\epsilon$, there is a $b$ where the inequality is true. Probably should fix that. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the following (unconditional) inequality due to Robin:
$$\sigma(n)<e^\gamma n\log\log n+\frac{0.6483 n}{\log\log n}$$
for $n\geq 3$. Therefore, to have the inequality you ask it's enough to have
$$e^\gamma n\log\log n+\frac{0.6483 n}{\log\log n}\leq(e^\gamma+\varepsilon)n\log\log n.$$
Elementary manipulations show that this is equivalent to
$$n\geq e^{e^{\sqrt{0.6483/\varepsilon}}},$$
so we may take the right-hand side as the upper bound for $b$, provided it's at least $3$.

There are better inequalities known nowadays, for instance the following due to Axler (*A new upper bound for the sum of divisors function*) gives
$$\sigma(n)<e^\gamma n\log\log n+\frac{0.1209 n}{(\log\log n)^2},$$
for $n>2520$, and we can similarly derive an upper bound for $b$:
$$b\leq e^{e^{\sqrt[3]{0.1209/\varepsilon}}}$$
if the right-hand side is at least $2520$.

As for finding the exact value of $b$, this already shows that this is in principle algorithmically possible, since we just have to find the largest $n$ smaller than the given bound for a given $\varepsilon$.

If we admit conjectural bounds, by results of Robin under RH the inequality holds for $\varepsilon=0$ for $n>5040$, and therefore $b\leq 5040$ for all $\varepsilon$, and for all small enough values of $\varepsilon$ this is exact. Therefore under RH, $b=5040$ for small enough $\varepsilon$.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need! +1 and accepted! Thorough as always!

Answer (score -1):

- The definition of $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sigma(n)}{n \ln \ln n}=e^\gamma$ is $$f(n) = \sup_{m \ge n} \frac{\sigma(m)}{m \ln \ln m}, \qquad \lim_{n \to \infty}  f(n) = e^{-\gamma}$$
- $\forall \epsilon>0, \exists b,\forall n \ge b,| f(n) -e^{-\gamma}|<\epsilon$ is the definition of $\lim_{n \to \infty}  f(n) = e^{-\gamma}$.
- $\lim_{n \to \infty}  f(n) = e^{-\gamma}$ follows from Mertens theorems.
- Robin Nicolas Lagarias proved that the RH holds iff $\forall n,f(n) = e^{-\gamma}$.
- Thus $f(n)$ is computable iff the RH is (dis)provable. If it is computable then for a fixed $\epsilon$ the smallest $b$ is computable.

Comment: Well, can an estimate/upper bound of $b$ be established?

Comment: Mertens theorems.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I still don't understand how that helps.

Comment: $\lim_{n \to \infty}  f(n) = e^{-\gamma}$ is one of Mertens theorems together with its rate of convergence.

Comment: Ok, I got that, but I'm not really connecting the two.

Comment: I cannot guess what you don't understand.

Comment: What I mean, how does this help me find an estimate/upper bound on $b$?

Comment: What "this". Mertens theorems are proven in dozen of places on the internet and on this website. The result is $\sigma(n)/n \le e^{-\gamma} \ln \ln n (1+C/\ln \ln n)$.

Comment: Wait, what is $C$?

Comment: It is a constant that nobody cares about. Do you really want me to check if $C=2$ works ? Some effective bounds are in there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number Also can you stop asking 50 useless questions and work by yourself ? I told you 3 weeks ago to look at the Robin Lagarias papers. It is obvious you never did it, continuing to ask pointless questions about $\sigma(n)/n$.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm making you mad, but why are the questions useless. Also, what paper specifically, because I doubt (though I may be wrong) any paper you sent me has that result.

Comment: As usual in maths the result is useless only the proof serves. I know how to prove the result but I don't know the constant, if I spend one hour writing the proof I will find a constant that works. If you only care of the constant then search "Robin criterion RH" and see what you find (but then don't open questions on MSE)

Comment: A quick google search leads nowhere, and are you sure you mean $e^{-\gamma}$ because everywhere I look, I only see $e^\gamma$.

Comment: I also looked back at all my old questions, you never sent me a link to any paper.

Comment: Also, I think you sent me the wrong Wikipedia link.

Comment: Also, I talked about your inequality with some of my more math-inclined friends, and they said your inequality is wrong if you have $e^{- \gamma}$, no matter what constant $C$ is.